# Which one is best to maintain healthy body either yoga or Gym?

Tags: recovery, health, health-risk, tips, maintenance

Nowadays we don't considering our body with day to day life, all are working day night shifts in our office environments with in front of machines and computers etc.,definitely they will affect our health in a certain period, after that only we recognize something went wrong in our health and take some consideration or remedy for that, so in that situation which one is best to maintain healthy body either **Yoga** or **Gym**.

Comment: _"As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."_

Comment: If someone likes Yoga more the best exercise is Yoga, if someone likes to go to the Gym, he should go to the Gym. If you are not sure, you should try both and either decide or do both. Anything is better than nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really asking is all that clear here. You can make an argument for either really, but people's individual situations will vary widely. This can be a debatable question and answer, and "one size fits all" may not be the most appropriate. Are you trying to ask about your own situation? If so please update your question and add some more information. Be sure to ask something practical based on a problem you face as stated in the [faq#dontask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you do at the gym.  Yoga helps with balance and flexibility.  The gym can help with a myriad of things, depending on what you choose to do when you go there.

Judging by your OP, you want an alternative to the sedentary and complacent lifestyle that results from working in an office setting.  Have you thought about playing organized sports?  They can do miracles for your health, while never really giving you the feeling that you are "working out".  If this isn't an option, going to the gym and doing the elliptical, some biking or getting on the treadmill will have the same effects.

Of course, strength training is always an option at the gym, but is much more time consuming and diet-constricting.

Which leads to my next point: Diet. What you put in your body is just as important as all of the exercise you choose to undertake.  With the right diet, you could get away with around 2 hours a week of exercise, and still maintain a healthy body and weight.

I work as an IT professional, and you'd be surprised if you saw our office and the staff.  We exercise together regularly, have a softball team, ball hockey team, etc... We share healthy recipes all the time, and even have an awesome [protein bar recipe](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dv-LcIC5gtc) that we all use.  Its quite motivational if you get your friends and co-workers involved with getting healthy at the same time.

Good Luck!

Comment: No problem!  Don't worry about the forum police here, it's the same thing all over the stack exchange.  You give people a shred of authority and they think they are superman.  Your question had merit, and deserved an answer. +1

Comment: Cheers Marco :-)

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc If you want to talk about the site, you should post on [meta].

Comment: @Informaficker Thanks for the suggestion! I'm not talking about the site though, I'm talking about its users and their sense of entitlement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're stating the question clearly...it's sort of asking: what's better salad or a restaurant..??..you can do yoga at home, the gym or a yoga studio - on the other hand a gym might be able to provide yoga, weight training, aerobic exercises, training classes, etc.  Being healthy consists of a good diet and regular exercise...set some realistic goals, find out what type of exercise interests you and go for it.